# How do I create a Cocoa window programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

My Cocoa app needs some small dynamically generated windows. How can I programmatically create Cocoa windows at runtime?

This is my non-working attempt so far. I see no result whatsoever.

```
NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
NSUInteger styleMask =    NSBorderlessWindowMask;
NSRect rect = [NSWindow contentRectForFrameRect:frame styleMask:styleMask];

NSWindow * window =  [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:rect styleMask:styleMask backing: NSBackingStoreRetained    defer:false];
[window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
[window display];
```

Answer (score 152, accepted):

The problem is that you don't want to call `display`, you want to call either `makeKeyAndOrderFront` or `orderFront` depending on whether or not you want the window to become the key window. You should also probably use `NSBackingStoreBuffered`.

This code will create your borderless, blue window at the bottom left of the screen:

```
NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
NSWindow* window  = [[[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame
                    styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                    backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                    defer:NO] autorelease];
[window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];

//Don't forget to assign window to a strong/retaining property!
//Under ARC, not doing so will cause it to disappear immediately;
//  without ARC, the window will be leaked.
```

You can make the sender for `makeKeyAndOrderFront` or `orderFront` whatever is appropriate for your situation.

Comment: Just curious to the person who found my answer /so/ unhelpful as to vote it down... why was it unhelpful?

Comment: Don't worry about the down-voter Jason. I found your answer helpful.

Comment: Works great. The downvote must be because you're initiating with "winRect", not "frame", should be fixed.

Comment: @Karolis - Thanks, I hand't noticed that mistake... fixed it tho.

Comment: I figured ARC had something to do with why my window would not show.

Answer (score 46):

A side note, if you want to programatically instantiate the application without a main nib, in the main.m file / you can instantiate the AppDelegate as below. Then in your apps Supporting Files / YourApp.plist *Main nib base file / MainWindow.xib* delete this entry. Then use Jason Coco's approach to attach the window in your AppDelegates init method.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h":

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  [NSApplication sharedApplication];

  AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
  [NSApp setDelegate:appDelegate];
  [NSApp run];
  [pool release];
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks. Searched long for this answer. Perfect! With the new Objective-C 3.0 better to use @autorelease {...}

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

instead of

```
[window display];
```

Is that what you're aiming for?

Answer (score 5):

Translating the top rated answer to modern swift (5) gives you something akin to this:

```
var mainWindow: NSWindow!

...

mainWindow = NSWindow(
    contentRect: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 200),
    styleMask: [.titled, .resizable, .miniaturizable, .closable],
    backing: .buffered,
    defer: false)
mainWindow.backgroundColor = .blue
mainWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(mainWindow)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've come up with myself:

```
NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(100, 100, 200, 200);
NSUInteger styleMask =    NSBorderlessWindowMask;
NSRect rect = [NSWindow contentRectForFrameRect:frame styleMask:styleMask];
NSWindow * window =  [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:rect styleMask:styleMask backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered    defer:false];
[window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront: window];
```

This displays a blue window. I hope this is the optimal approach.

Comment: Don't forget to release it, and to assign it to a strong or retaining property (the latter is especially important under ARC: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7198562/30461 ).